# Weird error in multi-line Batch-file printing

Tags: batch-file

I've been working on a project for myself, that produces a grid in batch, that can have specific points accessed and altered for better graphics with batch games and the like.

```batch-file
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

!x!
:::::::::::
:: ALIAS ::
:::::::::::
:@alias
    set x=exit/b
    goto:@main
    !x!
:::::::::::
:: MAIN  ::
:::::::::::
:@main
call:$Canvas _canvas 16 16 .
set px=%~1
set py=%~2
set _canvas_point[!px!][!py!]=#
!_canvas#draw!

!x!
:::::::::::
::OBJECTS::
:::::::::::
:@objects
!x!
:$Canvas
    set this=%~1
    set /a !this!_width=%~2
    set /a !this!_height=%~3
    set !this!_default_char=%~4
    set !this!#draw=call:#$canvas_proto_draw !this!
    for /L %%i in (1, 1, !%this%_height!) do (
        for /L %%j in (1, 1, !%this%_width!) do (
            set !this!_point[%%j][%%i]=!%this%_default_char!
            set !this!_row[%%i]=!%this%_row[%%i]!!%this%_point[%%j][%%i]!
            )
        )
    !x!
    :#$Canvas_proto_draw
        set this=%~1
        for /L %%i in (1, 1, !%this%_height!) do (
        for /L %%j in (1, 1, !%this%_width!) do (
            set !this!_row[%%i]=!%this%_row[%%i]!!%this%_point[%%j][%%i]!
            )
        )
        for /L %%i in (1, 1, !%this%_height!) do (
            echo !%this%_row[%%i]!
            )
    !x!
```

My problem occurs with the final output: giving it `1, 1` will result in a point showing up roughly halfway across the top row. I have no idea why this occurs, and need help. I've combed through all of the output with echo turned on and the value `_canvas_point[1][1]` does get the value of `#` on the update.

Here is the output:

```batch-file
C:\Home>canvas 1 1
................#...............
................................
................................
................................
................................
................................
................................
................................
................................
................................
................................
................................
................................
................................
................................
................................

C:\Home>
```

[Here](https://pastebin.com/5r3ek2G0) is a pastebin link with the output having `@echo on`

Quick things:
Yes, this is a feeble attempt at object oriented programming in batch-file
Yes, I know other languages are better for this kind of thing, I just want to do it with batch-file
Yes, I have weird stylistic choices with names and labels and such. It's so I can read it better, seeing as labels are used for both goto locations and function labels.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the below example comes close to what you're trying to accomplish (object oriented .BAT file approach):

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

rem  Initialize object "_canvas" (index numbers are row then column)
call :#$proto_init _canvas 16 16 .

rem  Set a few "_canvas" array characters to non-default values
call :#$proto_set  _canvas  1  1 ?
call :#$proto_set  _canvas  8  8 #
call :#$proto_set  _canvas 16 16 $

rem  Display "_canvas"
call :#$proto_draw _canvas
endlocal
exit/b


:#$proto_init
set /a %1_height=%2, %1_width=%3, %1_len=%2 * %3
set %1_default_char=%4
set %1_data=X
for /l %%i in (1, 1, !%1_len!) do set %1_data=!%1_data!!%1_default_char!
exit /b


:#$proto_set
for /f %%i in ('set /a ^(%2 - 1^) * !%1_height! + %3') do (
  for /f %%j in ('set /a %%i + 1') do (
     set %1_data=!%1_data:~0,%%i!%4!%1_data:~%%j!
  )
)
exit/b


:#$proto_draw
for /l %%w in (!%1_width!, 1, !%1_width!) do (
  for /l %%h in (1, %%w, !%1_len!) do echo !%1_data:~%%h,%%w!
)
exit /b
```

Comment: Thanks, for the help. I understand that the approach doesn't make much sense, but thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

In :#$Canvas_proto_draw

```
:#$Canvas_proto_draw
set this=%~1
for /L %%i in (1, 1, !%this%_height!) do (
 SET "!this!_row[%%i]="
 for /L %%j in (1, 1, !%this%_width!) do (
...
```

You may observe that your displayed data is 32 columns x 16 rows. This is caused by not clearing out each of the rows before appending the values.